# function is not running completly instead moving to other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

In my route
`router.get("/", verifyAdmin, getUsers);`

It should first verify admin then move to the getUsers function.

but instead it is moving towards getUsers function.

Routes:

```
import express from "express";
import {
  updateUser,
  deleteUser,
  getUser,
  getUsers,
} from "../controllers/user.js";
import { verifyAdmin, verifyUser,verifyToken } from "../middlewares/verifytoken.js";


const router = express.Router();

//UPDATE
router.put("/:id", verifyUser, updateUser);

//DELETE
router.delete("/:id", verifyUser, deleteUser);

//GET
router.get("/:id", verifyUser, getUser);

//GET ALL
router.get("/", verifyAdmin, getUsers);      // Problem is occouring here

export default router;
```

Middlewares:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const JWT_KEY = "jwt";    // for development its here only

export const verifyToken = (req,res,next) => { 
    const token = req.cookies.access_token;
    if(!token) return res.status(404).json("You are not authenticated");

    jwt.verify(token,JWT_KEY,(err,user)=>{
        if(err) return res.status(403).json("Token is invalid");

        req.user =user;
        
        next();
    })
   

};

export const verifyUser = (req, res,next) => {
 verifyToken(req, res, next,()=>{               // This section is not working
    if(req.user._id === req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin){
        next();
    }else{
       return next(res.status(403).json("You are not allowed to access this."));
    }
 })
    

}

export const verifyAdmin = (req, res,next) => {
    verifyToken(req,res,next,() => {
       
      if (req.user.isAdmin) {
       return next();
      } else {
        return res.status(403).json("you are not admin");
      }
    });
  };
```

User controllers:

```
import User from "../models/User.js";

//Update User
export const updateUser = async(req,res) =>{

    try {
        const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$set:req.body},{new:true});

        res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json(error);
    }
}


//Delete User
export const deleteUser = async(req,res) =>{

    try {
        await User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);

       return res.status(200).json("User has been deleted");
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json(error);
    }
}


// getUser
export const getUser = async(req,res) =>{

    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
       return res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json(error);
    }
}


// Get All Users

export const getUsers = async(req,res) =>{

    try {
        const users = await User.find();
       return res.status(200).json(users);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your actual app routing code? Because these are just middleware functions, and don't know anything "what runs next". Only that they should check one thing, call `next()` if everything's good, and call `next(some error thing here)` if things aren't. Your `verifyAdmin` should not depend on `verifyToken`, that should just be a middleware chain on your route.

Comment: `verifyToken` does not take a fourth parameter. Nor does it even attempt to use a callback.

Comment: const router = express.Router();

//UPDATE
router.put("/:id", verifyUser, updateUser);

//DELETE
router.delete("/:id", verifyUser, deleteUser);

//GET
router.get("/:id", verifyUser, getUser);

//GET ALL
router.get("/", verifyAdmin, getUsers);

export default router;

Comment: Not in a comment, just update your post =) But also as Vlaz mentions, if you're using the middleware signature `req, res, next` then there is no fourth argument to pass along.

Comment: You never run it so it never runs

Comment: It works. didn't know that there is no fourth argument after next. changed that anonymous function  into another function outside